Is there a name for the category formed from the unions of the objects and morphisms of slice and coslice categories with respect to a common object?
My question is about the terminology and syntax for a particular construction.
In plain language, I want to know how to refer to the thing that aggregates all the morphisms that involve a particular object from a a category.  I will overexplain this below to prevent ambiguity.
Setup
A category C has objects Ob(C) and morphisms Mor(C).
We consider an object x ∈ Ob(C).

Let From(x) be a subset of Mor(C) containing every f ∈ Mor(C) where source(f) = x.

Let To(x) be a subset of Mor(C) containing every f ∈ Mor(C) where target(f) = x.


We can form comma categories by considering From(x) and To(x) as the objects of their respective categories:

x\C is the under / coslice category where Ob(x\C) = From(x)
x/C is the over / slice category where Ob(x/C) = To(x)

Question
A category D has objects Ob(D) and morphisms Mor(D).

Ob(D) = Ob(x\C) ∪ Ob(x/C)
Mor(D) = Mor(x\C) ∪ Mor(x/C)

By convention,

What name is given to the category D with respect to the category C?

What syntax has been used to represent D with respect to the category C?

I defined D by treating two categories (x\C and x/C) as ordered pairs of sets and taking the unions of sets in the same position.  While it strikes me that this process does not generally form categories, sometimes it does.  When it does, is there a common name for the operation?  Formally, is there a symbol conventionally used for the operation ϴ when ϴ(L,R) = (Ob(L) ∪ Ob(R),Mor(L) ∪ Mor(R))?



This construction always forms a category; it's just the disjoint union of categories. So you're taking the disjoint union of the slice and coslice categories. But why do you want to do this?
